# What are these things under Airliners wing?

Tags: wing

As the picture below, what are these triangle components for? I find these normally installed under the Flaps. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Those are called [anti-shock bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-shock_body) and are placed on the wing to reduce [wave shock drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_drag).

Comment: Of course one could argue it's a chicken-egg-problem. But I think the designers put the actuation system for the flaps under the wings because those are really needed. And they will cover them aerodynamically. Only then they will look at the area-rule and might adjust the size of the cover. They will certainly not start with "anti-shock bodies" and figure out later on if the actuation system will fit inside.